Can a compact group have an infinite sequence of closed subgroups?
If $G$ is a copmact Hausdorff group then can there be, in some case of $G$, a sequence $G_i$, $i\ge0$ such that $G_0=G$ and $G_{n+1}$ is a closed proper subgroup of $G_n$ for all $n\ge0$ (proper meaning $G_n\neq G_{n+1}$)?
My thoughts:
I know that Haar measure would have to converge to $0$, but since subgroups can have measure $0$ this doesn't really get me anywhere. Also, I am aware that there are "reverse" sequences, for example the set of all $2^k$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ are closed subgroups of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and I can stack them in the opposite direction but this also doesn't get me anywhere. I also know (if I am not mistaken) that all compact groups are topologically generated by a finite set, but I am not aware of a bound $N$ such that all sets of at least $N$ elements generate the whole group, so I can't use something like this as a bound.

Yes. For example we can take $G = \mathbb{Z}_p$ to be the $p$-adic integers and $G_n = p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$. Each of the successive quotients $G_n/G_{n+1}$ is the finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/p$. In this example all the Haar measures are even nonzero. This group is Pontryagin dual to the Prüfer $p$-group $\mu_{p^{\infty}} \cong \mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1}{p} \right]/\mathbb{Z}$ of $p$-power roots of unity so your idea about roots of unity is relevant.

I also know (if I am not mistaken) that all compact groups are topologically generated by a finite set

This is false (although it is true in familiar examples); a counterexample is given by the "Cantor group" $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^{\mathbb{N}}$ given by the product of countably many copies of the finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/2$, equipped with the product topology. This group is abelian and every element has finite order so every finitely generated subgroup is finite (hence closed). The Cantor group also admits an infinite decreasing sequence of closed proper subgroups where $G_n$ is the kernel of the first $n$ coordinate projections, and similar to the above example $G_n/G_{n+1} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$.
Edit: Here's a funny characterization of which compact abelian groups are topologically finitely generated. First, for every $n$ there's a free compact abelian group on $n$ generators, which is given by the Bohr compactification $B(\mathbb{Z}^n)$. This group, by definition, satisfies $\text{Hom}(B(\mathbb{Z}^n), S^1) \cong T^n$, so it can be constructed as the Pontryagin dual of $T^n$ equipped with the discrete topology.
Now a compact abelian group $A$ is topologically finitely generated iff it admits a surjective homomorphism $B(\mathbb{Z}^n) \twoheadrightarrow A$. Taking Pontryagin duals, this is equivalent to the existence of an injective homomorphism $\widehat{A} \twoheadrightarrow T^n$. So the possible values of $A$ are exactly the Pontryagin duals of arbitrary subgroups of $T^n$.
This includes finitely generated abelian groups, whose Pontryagin duals are the compact abelian Lie groups. But it also includes, for example, sums of Prüfer groups, whose Pontryagin duals are products of groups of $p$-adic integers. And we also have examples like localizations $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1}{p} \right]$, whose Pontryagin duals are solenoids.

Great answer! You addressed every bit of my question, thank you.
